# Are there feline creatures in the Star Wars Universe?

Tags: star-wars

I wonder if cats or creatures similar to cats exist in the Star Wars Universe.
And if yes, what are these creatures, like humanoid cats or more like predators like tigers etc?

Or are there any references that some species had cats or something else as pets?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cat

Comment: There's at least [one](http://cdn2.business2community.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/tumblr_mlvuaqYqRO1r1kao4o1_500.jpg)...

Comment: I'm not much of a cat person, but [this](http://static2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20110108061458/slaveleia/images/d/d1/Salacious.jpg) looks like one to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.** *(However, we see mentions rather infrequently, and from the source list on Wookieepedia, there may not be any Disney-level canon. I'm not sure if the species mentioned below appear in Disney canon or not)*

From the Star Wars fandom page on [cats](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cat):

> A cat was a type of domesticated animal that made vocalizations that sounded like "meow." Ken occasionally wished he possessed a cat or a dog instead of his pet mooka, Zeebo. The spukamas was a common housecat on Corellia. The pittin was another domesticated cat-like creature, as was the felinx. Like cats, they came in many colors and enjoyed batting at strings. Reekcats were another species.
>
> There were also several sentient feline species in the galaxy, such as the the Cantrosians, the Cathar, the Tinnell, and the Togorians. Some cat-like sentient species, such as Orryxians and Catumen, were often nicknamed "Cats."

We see mentions of cats proper only in passing throughout the series, but they do exist. And from the list above, we see the sentient types (others have been referred to as "catlike" in novels, but this may have been a mention of their reflexes rather than their genetics).

A Togorian:

[image]

A Catumen:

[image]

Comment: The best canon example is probably the [nexu](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Nexu/Canon). The [Cathar](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cathar_%28species%29) are another example of a (Legends) feline humanoid species.

Comment: @null - Actually the best canon example is that they're mentioned in the novelisation of ANH

Comment: @Richard - yes, but due to the confusion surrounding the selective canon of the novels I left that detail out.

Comment: @SSumner - The novels are canon **where they relate to events that occurred during the films**.

Comment: @Richard - yeah, but I haven't read the ANH novelization, and the wiki page doesn't state when it occurs

Comment: @SSumner - See below.

Comment: @TheFallen Please note that links were updated so they don't someday stop working.  Also, there no longer is a site called "Wikia", so that reference will be increasingly meaningless.

Answer (score 17):

Yes. [Loth-Cats](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Loth-cat) are part of Disney canon. [image]

Comment: That. Is. Hideous. Eye bleach please!

Answer (score 7):

According to the official novelisations, there *are* cats in the Star Wars universe.

> “What is it, Artoo?” A short burst of beeping came in response.
>   Another moment, and there was no need for highly attuned sensors. For
>   a minute or two more, the corridor remained deathly silent. Then **a
>   faint scrape, scrape could be heard, like a cat at a door,** from
>   somewhere above. That strange noise was produced by heavy footsteps
>   and the movement of bulky equipment somewhere on the ship’s hull.
>   <sub><sup>[Star Wars : A New Hope (Novelisation)](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_IV:_A_New_Hope_%28novel%29)</sup></sub>

and

> He [Vader] purred, in the pit of his throat, **like a wild cat** smelling game on
>   the air. -  <sub><sup>[Star Wars - Return of the Jedi (Novelisation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi_%28novel%29)</sup></sub>

Comment: Those are both examples of simile - the descriptions are there to help the reader understand the description in the context of their own understanding and does not guarantee that the listener in either case would use the phrase "cat". It would be rather frustrating to read "He purred, in the pit of his throat, like are wild mooka" - with no other indication of what a mooka is.

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid - Although you're not wrong, I'm choosing to take the book literally.

Comment: @JakeGould It doesn't necessarily imply that. If the narrator is in our current universe and is recounting a history of the Star Wars universe, they could use similes which only make sense with our cultural context. (I'm not saying that's the case here though.)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what level of canonical-ness the video games hold, but Knights of the Old Republic has [Juhani](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Juhani), a Cathar (essentially a catgirl) Jedi who joins your team and can be a potential love interest for the main character.

Answer (score 0):

[Fandom](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Feline/Legends) lists a few species of felines, including the [manka cats](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Manka_cat).